# Google Service Account doesn't have permission to create folder

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-api-ruby-client

In Google Cloud Platform, I created a project.
Then I enabled Google Drive API for that project.
Then I created a service account.

I was able to upload file to Google Drive with that service account successfully.

But when I tried to create a folder using that service account:

```ruby
authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
    json_key_io: File.open(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH),
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata')

drive_service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
drive_service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
drive_service.authorization = authorizer

metadata = Google::Apis::DriveV3::File.new(name: folder_name)
folder = drive_service.create_file(metadata,
    fields: 'id',
    content_type: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
)
```

I got `insufficientPermissions` error

> /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/google-api-client-0.50.0/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:228:in
> `check_status': insufficientPermissions: Insufficient Permission:
> Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
> (Google::Apis::ClientError)

I looked around but couldn't not figure out how to grant necessary permission to the service account to create a folder.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The Google drive [file.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) method requires consent to be granted to the application with one of the following scopes

[image]

You appear to be using, which is not high enough permissions to create a file or in this case a directory.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
```

Tip: if you are using a service account there is really no reason not to just always use the full drive scope. You control the service account anyway.

Comment: I tried to configure an OAuth consent screen, but it didn't help. It doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the consent screen Its in your code. Your code is requesting the wrong scope of authorization.  **scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata')**  <-- change that

Comment: I used the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and the result is a file, not a folder. I followed the idea on [this github thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/issues/722) to change the scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata` and got permission error.